# What will happen if one electronic charge is given to a conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, conductors

I was taught in my physics class that if some charge is given to a conductor then the charge gets distributed over its entire surface.

But what will happen if just **an electron ( a point charge)** was given to the conductor ? What does it even mean for an electron to get distributed ?

Comment: Well, that conductor has lots of electrons in it already, so, yes, they all redistribute a bit to accommodate the extra one.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that a statement like "the charge gets distributed over its entire surface" is based on a simplifying model of electric charges, one that approximates "the real thing" quite well under the correct circumstances.

Most of the time, we deal with charges way greater than one electron's. While a single electron remains a point charge that can only be located at a single point in the conductor, when having many electrons, they will distribute over the surface (as far as that's possible, given that a single electron can't be split into halves).

Dealing with billions of individual electrons and their interactions can be done with enough computer power, but is very time-consuming, so we use a model that treats charges as continuous entities, not composed of single particles. This model gives results that match reality very well if the charge is large enough.

The model can't adequately describe single-electron cases ("correct circumstances" for this model is having many, many electrons).

But in typical engineering situations, you'll have charges large enough (consisting of enough electrons) for the continuous model to work perfectly well.